# Run a HTML site in localhost on OS X

Tags: macos, web, localhost

When I want to set up a site in the site folder on my Mac (running Snow Leopard) if it's a PHP site I don't have any problem running it my localhost in my browser, but if it's a simple HTML site if I run it in localhost I have the 403 Forbidden message:

**Forbidden**

**You don't have permission to access /mysite/index.php on this server.**

It is basically searching for the index.php as default page. I checked in my httpd.conf and the DirectoryIndex is set as index.html.
I'm a little confused now!

Any idea?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

A 403 error code means your browser cannot access the requested URL. It can be caused by many reason: Here is a [checklist](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/apache-403-forbidden-error-and-solution/). Check every options. I think you will get your solution

Take a look at [here](http://techtrouts.com/mac-os-x-105-web-sharing-forbidden-403-on-httplocalhostusername/) carefully.You should find a solution

Comment: Yes I know what's the 403, the problem is that it's trying to access /mysite/index.php while it cannot access or find /mysite/index.html. If I open the index.html file following the file path like: file:///Users/myname/Sites/mysite/index.html it works of course. I want it to run through localhost like: http://localhost/~myname/mysite/

Comment: Open your httpd.conf .Search for “Deny from all”.Alter that to “Allow from all“ if you find this. Then restart httpd.

Comment: If not solved then take a look here also http://support.apple.com/kb/TA25038?viewlocale=en_US

Comment: None of the above worked! :( I had already my myusername.conf file I added <Directory "/Users/myusername/Sites/touch/">
    Options Indexes MultiViews
    AllowOverride All
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
</Directory>

<IfModule dir_module>
    DirectoryIndex index.html
</IfModule> nothing worked. When I try to access localhost/~myusername/mysite I still have 403 error

Comment: Also Restart with $sudo httpd -k restart

Comment: tried but when I access it in localhost such as http://localhost/~myusername/mysite/index.html, I still got : Forbidden

You don't have permission to access /~myusername/mysite/index.html on this server. :( whyyyyyyy??????

Comment: :-(( okey take a look at the second link i had provided with my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Do a ls -al on mysite/ and check that the file and the folder are readable by you, like:

```
-rw-r--r--   1 yourusername  staff    111 11 Set 17:09 index.php
```

If not chmod it

```
chmod 644 mysite/index.php
chmod 755 mysite/
```

Comment: I did a ls -l in mysite folder and the index.html file shows like this: -rwxr-xr-x   1 maurizio  staff     7144  2 Sep 19:20 index.html What does it mean exactly?

Comment: It means you (the owner of the file) can read write and execute, then is the permissions for the group and at last for other users. More info on [filesystem permissions at Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_system_permissions#Symbolic_notation)